# Angular | How to subscribe to changes in array of objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my angular application, I have the following array of objects:

```
public data = [
{a: 0, b: [{q: 1, z: 2}]}
{a: 1, b: [{q: 4, z: 9}]}
]
```

**Question**: How can I subscribe to any changes in the array (also including changes in nested objects)?

**Expected result**: A function that fires every time `data` is changed

Comment: Create a state to wrap `data`, export an `Observable<?>` that others can observe, if changes to `data` are happening fire that observer.

Comment: Sweet, can you show me how this is done?

Comment: How exactly will you be changing `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a service to wrap your state (here you can also use more sophisticated frameworks like Redux but lets keep it simply for the start), this is usually a good idea to decouple your application

## state.service.ts

```
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs/index";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateService {

    private readonly subject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});

    public readonly observable: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable();

    public set(newValue: any): void {
        this.subject.next(newValue);
    }
}
```

then your component can register to `observable` to render it e. g. by using

```
public readonly value: Observable<any> = this.stateService.observable
    .pipe(map(_ => JSON.stringify(_)));
```

and to e. g. print out the value

```
<p *ngIf="value | async">{{(value | async)}}</p>
```

and if you are now using `set` to update the state the component will be refreshed automatically.

In general I found Angular applications are way easier to understand if your components and your application state are properly separated (remember Model-View-Controller?) so that your components do not contain any state themselves and are only binding the templates to the state via observables so that you do not need to care about refreshes and updates (remember Java Swing listeners?). And the state has a clearly defined interface to be interacted with so that no one fiddles in the internal structure of your application state.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example! I don't see this will fire a function if `data` is changed, i.e `data[0].b[1] = 8`

Comment: That's what I wrote with "and if you are now using set to update the state the component will be refreshed automatically." - using a pattern like mine you will not change data in any way but via methods on the state because otherwise you will not be able to observe changes on the underlying data.